# how to withdraw the ethereum from the wallet created programmatically

Tags: go-ethereum, ethereumj, ethereumjs

I need to create ethereum wallets in my web project for each user. The scenario is as below:

```
1.The user creates an account.
2.The project automatically Create an ethereum wallet for each user.
3.The project automatically send some ethereum to the user's wallet.
```

The questions are:

```
1.Is it an appropriate to use ethereumj to create the wallet for each user?
2.How can the user back up the ethereum wallet?
3.how can the user take out the ethereums from the wallet?
```

Comment: Your questions mention bitcoin; did you mean ether?

Comment: yes, i meant ether. I edited the question.

Answer (score 2):

1. No [ethereumj](https://github.com/ethereum/ethereumj) is a Java client implementation of the Ethereum yellow paper. It is a client.

Generate Ethereum addresses using a library such as [keythereum](https://github.com/ethereumjs/keythereum).

2. You mean Ethereum? You can create a feature to allow them to..
3. They can sign transactions using the private key that you generate for them which you have allowed them to download (see question 2).

Comment: Thanks Thomas. It was a typo and I really meant Ethereum. Is there any example for the 3 questions? Many thanks!